# Suppress error generated from Obsolete attribute

Tags: c#

I would like to find a way of treating the 'Obsolete' CS0619 compiler error generated as a warning instead.

The 'show as compiler error' is a constructor level property, as per the example:
`[Obsolete("XXX", true)]`

We are using a Nuget package that provides a method marked as obsolete using a compiler error - DocumentFormat.OpenXml v2.20.0.

Having recently checked previous stack overflow articles, it seems the only way to work around this issue is by resorting to reflection.

There is currently no compelling reason to make the change from v2.19.0, however I am genuinely curious to know how this can be done.

Documentation on the obsolete attribute is at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute?view=net-6.0

This is part of a github discussion at:
https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/discussions/1414
The context of the github discussion in part relates to how we can suppress the compiler error. We cannot use the alternative approach suggested by the obsolete message, as the obsolete method is required by a downstream microsoft nuget package.

I have tried:

1. repeating the exercise hoping for a different outcome.
2. convincing the package owners to just use compiler warnings instead of errors.
3. reviewing stack overflow articles where the outcome was to use reflection.
4. liaising with the package owners who have suggested this is possible through 'diaglostic ids' - what are these? LMGTFY doesn't shed any light.
5. Checking to see if there is a magical `#pragma error disable` - there is not.

Comment: Add to your .editorconfig; `[*.cs] dotnet_diagnostic.CS0612.severity = warning` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2022#set-rule-severity-in-an-editorconfig-file

Answer (score 0):

You can try and bypass it by using generics. This is assuming a parameterless ctor

```cs
public class Obsolete
{
    public string User { get; }
    [Obsolete("Use comething else", true)]
    public Obsolete()
    {
        User = "Test";
    }
}

public static T Create<T>() where T : class, new()
{
    return new T();
}

var obs = Create<Obsolete>();
```

Comment: That is clever! I probably should have supplied additional context, in that I do not construct the instance, rather it is an obsolete property exposed on an existing interface.